# Формирование буфера на С++ Пример на Go

Tags: c++, golang

Здравствуйте. Нужно сформировать буфер на С++ для отправки клиенту. 
В языке Go он представлен []byte:

```
fmt.Println(buffer.Bytes())

Output: [0 27 128 0 0 0 3 172 0 17 91 49 49 45 49 48 32 50 51 58 48 58 48 58 48 93 0]
```

Отправление происходит вот так:

```
    func WriteHandler(c net.Conn) {
            for v := range buffer.Bytes() {
            c.Write(v)
        }
    }
```

Пробовал:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"

using Poco::Net::SocketAddress;
using Poco::Net::ServerSocket;
using Poco::Net::StreamSocket;

void main(){
    int buffer[] = {0,27,128,0,0,0,3,172,0,17,91,49,49,45,49,48,32,50,51,58,48,58,48,58,48,93,0};

SocketAddress Address("127.0.0.1:1973");
ServerSocket Listen(Address);
StreamSocket client = Listen.acceptConnection();
int n = client.sendBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);

char buffers[1024];
int n1 = client.receiveBytes(buffers, sizeof(buffers) - 1);
buffers[n1] = '\0';
std::cout << "RESULT:" << buffers << "N:" << n1<< std::endl;
}
```

Должен придти пакет авторизации, а ничего не приходит.

Comment: Если не секрет, зачем вы вообще переписываете код с Go на C++? Если дело в производительности, то вам лучше потратить это время на [профилирование и оптимизацию](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs), чем на переписывание гошного кода на C++.

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение :) - смотрите, первый байт (кстати, в Go вы вроде отправляете **байты**, а в C++ - **int**ы?) - нулевой. Так что первый символ в `buffers` - нулевой. И при выводе в `cout`, естественно, ничего не выводится - так как получается, что в `buffers` хранится пустая строка... Чему равно по получении значение `n1`?

Comment: Хотелось бы научиться грамотно писать на С++, вдобавок интересуюсь эмуляторами, а сервер интересующей меня игры написан на Go.

Comment: @Harry Да. Скорее всего я должен не int строку отправлять, так я перевожу string в []byte. Сейчас выложу код получения []byte. n1 = 0.

Comment: Что-то я внимательнее глянул, вообще непонятно... У вас клиент ожидает входящее соединение? После чего сразу отправляет что-то там и ждет получения информации?

Comment: Вам следует приводить [MCVE](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) для воспроизведения вашей ошибки. Написать какую библиотеку в C++ используете, так как в отличии от golang в стандартной пока нет ничего для работы с сетью.

Comment: Это пример сервера. Он ждет подключение, потом отправляет пакет с датой, после чего получает пакерт с логином и паролем, зашифрованный на основе отправленного пактеа. Вот так получается буфер на Go https://play.golang.org/p/yNe-WXDggu

Comment: Это не то. С таким-же успехом вы могли бы сделать так:https://play.golang.org/p/aBHNr02uyb . Это никак не проясняет вопрос, так как в Go коде проблем нет.

Comment: Так формируется пакет в эмуляторе. Каким образом это сделать на С++?

Comment: Вот такой пакет должен придти http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=d482c2161e5044c1554485969d98495c

Comment: Вот мой http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=b534c46dd2dbc715b41cd4f4a01f8e41

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"

using Poco::Net::SocketAddress;
using Poco::Net::ServerSocket;
using Poco::Net::StreamSocket;

void main(){
    int8_t buffer[] = {0,27,128,0,0,0,3,172,0,17,91,49,49,45,49,48,32,50,51,58,48,58,48,58,48,93,0};

SocketAddress Address("127.0.0.1:1973");
ServerSocket Listen(Address);
StreamSocket client = Listen.acceptConnection();
int n = client.sendBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
}
```